# How to upload large file (about 1GB) by using ASP classic?

Tags: upload, vb6, activex

I want to upload some large file (about 1GB) by using ASP classic, it seems it's not hard on ASP.net, then what about ASP classic? I tried:

- no component upload class, like: NetRube_Upload.asp and etc., it's colud upload files with about 200m size, but 1GB does not. I don't know it's server (IIS) limit or client (browser) limit or problem of code itself.
- I think using some commercial components like ASPload or Huge Asp Upload can resolve this problem, but Unfortunately my project is also commercial, so I have to avoid to use these commercial components.
- Code by myself to develop a component (.dll) by using VB6 and install on server, I followed the instruction from Microsoft in here:

[How to upload files to a Web server by using ASP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299692/how-to-upload-files-to-a-web-server-by-using-asp)

But got error:

```
'800a005b' 
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

I'm not paste context because I fully followed the instruction and got this error.

So, could any anybody give me some suggest? Thank you!

Comment: Unless you are doing this for learning reasons I suggest you use something such as aspupload or abcupload rather than reinvent. Also, 800* errors are hard to debug without context and code. Plus you are about to get flamed for not providing sample code, explaining what you tried, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, cause I'm developing a commercial app including feature that upload large file in web, so I have to avoid to use other commercial components. All I want to do is upload large file through asp+dll, or some other way.

Comment: Well, if you have commercial drivers then time cost and productivity must be a concern, as well as robustness and support. My money would be on a commercial component but you must have your reasons.Still can't help without more context.

Comment: If you want to do this by hosting an ActiveX component *in a web page* then you simply can't - that only ever worked in IE and was removed as an option in IE11. For commercial software you cannot assume your clients are all using IE10 or below.

Comment: @Vanquished Wombat thank you for your answer, I will update my question.

Comment: @AlexK. I mean dll is install on server via regsvr32, then called component use Server.CreateObject("cc.function") on asp, so it's cross browser.

Comment: @user1928432 File upload to classic ASP is definitely possible as per your intention. You use a standard html input type=file or a more modern file upload selector that blings this up but it all ultimately comes to a multipart form post.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solved this problem by using solution of Microsoft dll development instrction in here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299692/how-to-upload-files-to-a-web-server-by-using-asp

however, you have to edit some codes to make it working and avoid the error '800a005b' occurred.

It upload 700m+ file successful by using classic ASP and VB6.